# How to initialize variables in a `tf.Module` in TF2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow2.0, I find that I can initialize variables in a Model in the following way

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, kwargs**):
        """ some definition here """
        self(tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,)))

    def call(self, x):
        """ some implementation """
```

But I cannot do something like

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, kwargs**):
        """ some definition here """
        self.step(tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,)))

    def step(self, x):
        """ some implementation """
```

This will gives error 
[image]
The reason I want to do the second is that I try to inherit `MyModel` from `tf.Module`, which has no `__call__` available --- Even if I define one, the same error arises. I'm wondering if there is a way to initialize variables in a class inherited from `tf.Module` like I did in the first code block?

Comment: Why do you use `tf.Module` instead of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` ?

Comment: Hi, @OlivierDehaene because I found that I don't need most of functionality of keras interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keras functional/symbolic API is only compatible with Keras (e.g. compile+fit) sadly.

You might be able to use `tf.zeros` instead (e.g. `self(tf.zeros(input_shape))`) although this may have undesirable side effects (e.g. like influencing your batch norm stats).

If you want a robust solution you might want to consider using `snt.build(self, input_shape)` [0] which is a utility function in [Sonnet 2](https://sonnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (a library containing a bunch of common `tf.Module`s).

[0] https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet/blob/v2/sonnet/src/build.py#L50

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Is there a naive TF2.0 way to initialize variables? I just need access to `trainable_variables` before the network starts training.

Comment: The simplest way would be to simply call your module(s) with an example input (e.g. zeros) before you start training. `model = MyModel(); model(tf.zeros(input_shape))  # Create all variables in model.`

Comment: It might be worth looking at this example https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet/blob/v2/examples/simple_mnist.py, it is not Sonnet specific (other than using Sonnet modules and optimizers). With your training loop structured this way you can see we delay requesting the parameters of the model until after we have computed our loss and gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've checked the example you provide. It gets the trainable variables after the forward pass. However, I want to get the trainable variables before the network is used. Also, as you said in the answer, using fake data such as zeros will introduce bias to batch normalization. I'm wondering if all these suggest TF2 does not natively support getting trainable variables before the first network pass?

Comment: Most TF modules (e.g. Keras/Sonnet) create variables the first time they are called. This is convenient since you don't need to specify input sizes at construction time. I would suggest taking another look at the source for `snt.build` as linked in the answer, the implementation boils down to `tf.function(module).get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(input_size, dtype))` which is a TF2 native solution to the problem of initializing variables but not triggering other stateful ops (e.g. assignment to batch stats). Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thank you so much. You really help me out!